# Comparing two string in Java not giving the expected result

Tags: java, android, string, string-comparison

I am beginner i want to get text in `EditText` and compare it with another string .

I want to check if text writed in `EditText` is equals a 'String' then show a `Toast` but it is not working

I debug and check the value of both are exactly admin but if block is not working and shows else block.

```
if (editText.getText().toString() == "admin") {
    //Never enter this block when i type "admin" in the EditText.
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"ok",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
} else {
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Wrong User Or Pass",
}
```

Comment: This is a `JAVA` problem, not android. Take a look to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/513839/2835520)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You have to use [String.equals()](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_equals.htm) method for string matching.

Change your code into this

```
    if (editText.getText().toString().equals("admin")) {
        //your code
    }
```

.

Answer (score 5):

do not use == to compare strings since strings are not primitive data types 
instead use user.equals("admin")

Answer (score 0):

You can user  `equalsIgnoreCase`.

This method compares this String to another String, ignoring case considerations. Two strings are considered equal ignoring case if they are of the same length, and corresponding characters in the two strings are equal ignoring case.

```
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


            if (user.equalsIgnoreCase("admin")) {
Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"ok",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
            else {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Wrong User Or Pass",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,user,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }

    });
```

Comment: why use ignore case ?

Comment: Ignore case is used if you dont care about if the `String` is writed in **Majuscule** or **Minuscule**.

Answer (score 0):

When i use this way i solved my problem.

```
  boolean result = String1.equals(String2);
    if (result)
    {
        return  true;
    }
    else
    {
        return  false;
    }
```